# Foreground segmentation when similar color distributions

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, image-segmentation, background-foreground

How can I segment my foreground object from background when they have similar color distributions? I am trying to detect/segment a steel buckle from a roughly similar gray background. 
Thanks!

Example input images:
[image: sample1]

[image: sample2]

Comment: Also, just to add, I tried segmentation using FG and BG GMM (K=5) models, but that doesn't work well as the detection produces good amount of FG pixels in BG area.

I also tried GrabCut, but it doesn't work as well. 

Any help is appreciated. Thanks !

Comment: can you post an example image?

Comment: Hello, thanks for responding. I have added two images in the original post for reference. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Using an edge detector could work.  After the edge detection, you are going to have to use some secondary interpretation to determine inside and outside of object to be segmented, but that should not be too bad if you can get a relatively clean edge.
Generally (depending on lighting) edges get slight relative shadowing, which allows edge detectors to place pretty clean lines around objects sitting on surfaces.

Comment: Hello, Thank you for responding. My foreground is a rectangular steel buckle lying over a bunch of vertical cables. The cables lie on a surface that has very similar color distribution to that of the buckle. 

For color based segmentation, the same surface interferes with the foreground, and most of the time my GMM model predicts foreground pixels there.

I have also tried edge based segmentation, and here the cables interfere with the edges of the buckle. I find it difficult to isolate the edges of the buckle from that of the cables then.

Comment: Thanks again. Let me know if you have any further suggestions. Much appreciated.